# ADFS SSO and Django powered web app hosted on linux server

Tags: django, single-sign-on, adfs

My scenario is that I have Django powered web application and I want to integrate ADFS SSO into it.

There are few questions that I want answer as I have never forayed into ADFS territory.

- How would my app be setup in this case?
- How will the authentication flow be?
- Would there be any changes to server stack that I use (nginx)? I mean would it work if I have application on nginx or do I need anything else to make it work?

Also, some pointers and cautions that I need to know before going forward with it. I know the question might be broad in scope but given the scenario I cant narrow it down because of my lack of knowledge about the subject matter

Comment: @BurhanKhalid that thread went dead. It was me who had asked it and you who replied it.

Comment: It doesn't mean you create duplicate questions.

Comment: Well it slipped out of my mind that I had created one, only when you linked it back as duplicated I found out. Thanks.